# Android 2d game engine why libgdx instead another

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, libgdx, game-engine

I dont know why, Im confused, Im trying to figure out a good game engine, althouth I m using libgdx, but I see that using this framework is a little dificult, because, it dosent have gui, like a colorfull work space where you put your actor, and draw your stage I mean, there we have game engine like unity 3d, unreal engine, but, Why people use libgdx, I have never open unity 3d but I m thinking to start learning cause I see videos on youtube with unity like profesionals video game, but When I look for libgdx games look like games of the 1960, or worst,

I start learning libgdx, I want to develop a 2d game using cards like pocker, and Im getting dificult, what do you think its faster, and easier, learn unity 3d(I have money to buy the license) or continue learning libgdx, I mean I only have like 5 days reading about libgdx, Im a beginer.

Comment: If you're thinking about giving unity3D a shot, probably the easiest way is to simply download the free version and start experimenting with it. Although unity is designs with 3d games in mind, it's still fairly simple to create 2d ones

Comment: You should probably use Unity.

Comment: I have used both Unity 3.x and libgdx. If you go for rapid and easy development, do Unity. It's also a lot of assets and scripts you could download/buy on their asset store, that often come in handy. Libgdx is free and could shorten the development time, but I found some things quite hard to use/modify. The documentation of Unity is a lot better. Props to the libgdx developers though, for creating a free framework to use!